# Há uma forma de criar um IDE baseada em IntelliJ?

Tags: ide, compiladores, intellij-idea, intellij

Com algumas pesquisas na internet descobri que IDEs como Android Studio e PHPStorm são IDEs baseadas na IntelliJ, cada uma com um propósito.

Como criar um IDE com base nela?

A ideia é criar uma IDE com botões para:

- criar projetos, com modelos de projetos com um sistema de pastas e arquivos que eu mesmo definir.
- chamar utilitários de linha de comando em *background*, para abrir navegador (executar) e até mesmo compilar (se por acaso quisesse chamar um *React* com os parâmetros do projeto para compilar um `apk` ou um `ipa`)
- local para configurar *paths* de JDK, SDK, React, etc (ou até mesmo um navegador padrão)

Enfim, criar IDEs para automatizar meu desenvolvimento com o que eu uso, seja com páginas apenas com HTML, CSS e JS ou estruturas com arquivos `.java` ou `.php` e criar modelos de projetos para diversos projetos, como compilar (se for o caso) e testá-los.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber, há uma forma,

Dá sim.

> e se sim qual, de criar uma IDE com base nela também.

É só você fazer um [*fork* do repositório da versão *communit* da IDE](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) e criar sua própria implementação.

Comment: Eu estava lendo, no link abaixo, e conclui que uma IDE IntelliJ customizada, nada mais é que uma distribuição dela com uns plugins já instalados, estou certo? Link: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/checkout_and_build_community.html

Comment: @LucasFerreiraBatista não necessariamente... Você pode fazer a sua própria versão dela independente de plugins. Só acho que não é uma atividade tão trivial assim

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade você não quer criar um IDE, você quer personalizar algumas poucas coisas. Nem sei se muito, parece só querer o [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/?fromMenu) e o [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/?fromMenu) ou [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/?fromMenu).

Mas se quiser realmente fazer um IDE se prepare para um trabalho hercúleo e nada trivial. De fato [IntelliJ é uma plataforma que pode ser usada como base para seu IDE](http://www.jetbrains.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983889).